# How to extract links from elements?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the links of every individual member but I am not getting output:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.asklaila.com/search/Delhi-NCR/-/doctors/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')

for link in soup.find_all('h2',class_='resultTitle'):
    link1 = link.find('a')
    print link1['href']
```

Comment: Did you try to `print(soup)` ? I am getting `403 Forbidden`

Comment: Could you post the `r.text` request part where the links you want to extract are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need request `url` with `header` param. [more details](https://2.python-requests.org//en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers)

Where `resultContent` top doctors in Delhi-NCR result div class, `cardWrap` every doctor cards div class.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Custom user agent'}
r = requests.get('https://www.asklaila.com/search/Delhi-NCR/-/doctors/',headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
resultContentArray = soup.find('div',{'class':'resultContent'}).find_all("div",{'class':'cardWrap'})

for rr in resultContentArray:
    title = rr.find('h2',{'class':'resultTitle'})
    link = rr.find("a",href=True)
    if link is not None:
        print(link['href'])
```

**O/P:**

```
https://www.asklaila.com/category/Delhi-NCR/-/doctors/doctor/?category=176
https://www.asklaila.com/search/Delhi-NCR/greater-kailash-1/doctors/
https://www.asklaila.com/search/Delhi-NCR/-/maternity-hospital/
https://www.asklaila.com/Delhi-NCR/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/madangir/dr-vp-kaushik/0Vm4m7jP/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/sector-19/dr-arvind-garg/1BEtXFWP/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/indira-puram/dr-sanjay-garg/kUUpPPzH/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/new-friends-colony/dr-rk-caroli/GK5X4dSI/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/vasant-vihar/dr-sourabh-nagpal/0v1s6pGr/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/ncr/care24/0bbotWCf/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/soami-nagar-north/sudaksh-physiotherapy-psychology-orthopaedic-psychiatry-clinic-/kJxps7Dn/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/vaishali-sector-3/dr-sb-singh/00PPdXnM/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/kaushambi/dr-uma-kant-gupta/0ivP1mJ6/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/vaishali-sector-4/dr-kanwal-deep/09eZqT9k/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/east-of-kailash/dr-harbhajan-singh/ngDklERb/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/uttam-nagar/dr-bb-jindal/0Z8u07oQ/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/greater-kailash-part-1/dr-raman-kapoor/kNFPgYfZ/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/dwarka-sector-7/dr-pankaj-n-surange/NpIBzM4K/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/vaishali-sector-3/dr-ritu-gupta/19IoQ4A7/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/vaishali-sector-5/dr-mala-bhattacharjee/ywTzyamp/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/vasundhara/dr-mohit-jindal/vN9FiMAd/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/janakpuri/dr-ravi-manocha/1Qe4iuK1/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/vikas-marg/sparsh/08ZpsI85/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/kamla-nagar/dr-deepak-guha/ETn71X1r/
https://www.asklaila.com/search/Delhi-NCR/-/doctors/20
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

- `html.parser`
- custom header `User-agent`
- `soup.select` feature

---

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get('https://www.asklaila.com/search/Delhi-NCR/-/doctors/', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

for link in soup.select('h2[class="resultTitle"] > a'):
    print(link['href'])
```

The output:

```
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/madangir/dr-vp-kaushik/0Vm4m7jP/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/sector-19/dr-arvind-garg/1BEtXFWP/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/indira-puram/dr-sanjay-garg/kUUpPPzH/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/new-friends-colony/dr-rk-caroli/GK5X4dSI/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/vasant-vihar/dr-sourabh-nagpal/0v1s6pGr/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/ncr/care24/0bbotWCf/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/soami-nagar-north/sudaksh-physiotherapy-psychology-orthopaedic-psychiatry-clinic-/kJxps7Dn/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/vaishali-sector-3/dr-sb-singh/00PPdXnM/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/kaushambi/dr-uma-kant-gupta/0ivP1mJ6/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/vaishali-sector-4/dr-kanwal-deep/09eZqT9k/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/east-of-kailash/dr-harbhajan-singh/ngDklERb/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/uttam-nagar/dr-bb-jindal/0Z8u07oQ/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/greater-kailash-part-1/dr-raman-kapoor/kNFPgYfZ/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/dwarka-sector-7/dr-pankaj-n-surange/NpIBzM4K/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/vaishali-sector-3/dr-ritu-gupta/19IoQ4A7/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/vaishali-sector-5/dr-mala-bhattacharjee/ywTzyamp/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/vasundhara/dr-mohit-jindal/vN9FiMAd/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/janakpuri/dr-ravi-manocha/1Qe4iuK1/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/vikas-marg/sparsh/08ZpsI85/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/sector-40/dr-amit-yadav/1ik21lZw/
```

Answer (score 0):

The server is looking for User-Agent in header to prevent users from **scraping** the content
you could set request headers as a work around.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = dict()
headers['User-Agent']= "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0"


r = requests.get('https://www.asklaila.com/search/Delhi-NCR/-/doctors/',headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
# with open('h.html','w') as w:
#     w.write(soup.text)
for link in soup.find_all('h2',class_='resultTitle'):
    link1 = link.find('a')
    print link1['href']
```

Should give you

https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/madangir/dr-vp-kaushik/0Vm4m7jP/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/sector-19/dr-arvind-garg/1BEtXFWP/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/indira-puram/dr-sanjay-garg/kUUpPPzH/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/new-friends-colony/dr-rk-caroli/GK5X4dSI/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/vasant-vihar/dr-sourabh-nagpal/0v1s6pGr/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/ncr/care24/0bbotWCf/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/soami-nagar-north/sudaksh-physiotherapy-psychology-orthopaedic-psychiatry-clinic-/kJxps7Dn/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/vaishali-sector-3/dr-sb-singh/00PPdXnM/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/vaishali-sector-4/dr-kanwal-deep/09eZqT9k/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/kaushambi/dr-uma-kant-gupta/0ivP1mJ6/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/east-of-kailash/dr-harbhajan-singh/ngDklERb/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/uttam-nagar/dr-bb-jindal/0Z8u07oQ/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/greater-kailash-part-1/dr-raman-kapoor/kNFPgYfZ/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/dwarka-sector-7/dr-pankaj-n-surange/NpIBzM4K/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/vaishali-sector-3/dr-ritu-gupta/19IoQ4A7/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/vaishali-sector-5/dr-mala-bhattacharjee/ywTzyamp/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/vasundhara/dr-mohit-jindal/vN9FiMAd/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/janakpuri/dr-ravi-manocha/1Qe4iuK1/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/vikas-marg/sparsh/08ZpsI85/
https://www.asklaila.com/listing/Delhi-NCR/kamla-nagar/dr-deepak-guha/ETn71X1r/

Answer (score 0):

**Using **SoupStrainer**

```
import httplib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

http = httplib2.Http()
status, response = http.request('https://www.asklaila.com/search/Delhi-NCR/-/doctors/')

for link in BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser', parse_only=SoupStrainer('a')):
    if link.has_attr('href'):
        print(link['href'])
```

Answer (score 0):

There are twenty correct links to retrieve for members. A concise way is to use css selector of parent class with child combinator to get `a` tag within

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.asklaila.com/search/Delhi-NCR/-/doctors/',headers= {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')
links = [item['href'] for item in soup.select('.resultTitle > a')]
print(links)
```